# Picasso placeholder scale and fit to center screen

Tags: android, animation, placeholder, picasso

I am trying to implement a placeholder animation with Picasso the animate a custom animation while loading from the web. I have looked for a lot of solutions and I cant find a way to scale down the animation and center it. The result is that sometimes the animation is stretched, centered, or playing in one corner.

The animation images are significantly smaller than the image view and the downloaded images.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(imageUri).fit()//.placeholder(R.drawable.progress_animation)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.progress_animation)
                        .into(mIconView);
```

Here is the animation definition:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="false">

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel1" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel2" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel3" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel4" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel5" android:duration="50" />
```

Any suggestions on how you can control the animation scale and position in Picasso, I couldn't find a way to use fit() or resize() because it effects only the final image and not the placeholder, and trying to use two of them creates a collision.

Comment: Face same issue  look this [Picasso Image Re sizing](https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit)

Answer (score 1):

i find a way using progress bar and call back.

```
 mProgressView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(f).fit()

                    .into(mIcon,new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            mProgressView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });
```

here is the layout section

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"

>
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:id="@+id/ib_place_dialog_image"
    android:maxHeight="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:scaleX="0.4"
    android:scaleY="0.4"
    android:layout_width="128dp"
    android:layout_height="128dp"
    android:id="@+id/cliff_image_progress_bar"

    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_animation"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

and the animation

```
   <animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="false">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_0" android:duration="30" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_0" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_0" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_1" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_2" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_3" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_4" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_5" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_6" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_7" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_8" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_9" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_10" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_11" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_12" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_13" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_14" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_15" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_16" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_17" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_18" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_19" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_20" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_21" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_22" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_23" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_24" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_25" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_26" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_27" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_28" android:duration="30" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_29" android:duration="30" />



</animation-list>
```

Comment: Thanks, the callback was really useful.

Answer (score 0):

i used the code of loran ditsum but i changed the onSucces method =

in the xml the Post_image ScaleType is centerinside

```
    Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(imagen)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.progress_animation)
                    .into(Post_image,new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            Post_image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY); 
// when the image is loaded it changes the scaletype

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 Picasso.get()
                        .load(source).resize(1650,700)
                        .centerCrop(Gravity.CENTER).into(imageView, new Callback()
```